# Limit doesn't exist

Tags: limits

I know for a limit to exist on a LH/RH function they must be equal.  So to prove that the limit doesn't exist in this situation can I just do what I have done?
[image]

Edit, I think I need to make it more like this which is by the 3.14 Theorem????

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is right what you did :)

Comment: I would have used that if you take $0$, no matter what $r>0$ you say, $0$ will have continuum amount of negative and positive elements too within that $r$ range, so the limit can't exist.

Comment: I edited it... I think it fits more in terms of proving ..?

Comment: It is totally good. :)